# Firefox shows numbers and symbols as emoji, how to disable this?

Tags: firefox, fonts, unicode, emoji

I've been digging and searching the web for an answer to this, but to no avail. What is causing this:

[image]

As you can see, it makes it hard to read numbers. Setting Firefox to safe mode does not fix it.

#### A bit more info, though this is clearly not a fix.

Disabling the font for the top bar made things normal again:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens if you override the font for "Latin" and *don't* allow pages to choose their own fonts?

Comment: As the example comes from stack exchange I don't think that this page is overriding fonts with emojis.

Comment: It has nothing to do with which site I use, or whether it uses custom fonts. It's also weirdly inconsistent, as sometimes (on the same site) it will work just fine without doing this.

Comment: Can you give us a list of plugins you're running on firefox? Maybe even userscripts?

Comment: @Videonauth it wouldn't make a difference. Like I said, even running in safemode doesn't fix it. I even tried creating a new profile - that didn't fix it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78570/discussion-on-question-by-rolandixor-firefox-shows-numbers-and-symbols-as-emoji).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem - emojione. I was tipped off by a suggested question in the sidebar of this question: [EmojiOne Color font doesn't replace black and white emoji font in Firefox or Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808946/emojione-color-font-doesnt-replace-black-and-white-emoji-font-in-firefox-or-chr?rq=1)

While the demo page doesn't show these number emoji, I did notice some of the other symbols were there. Removing the emojione package has returned my numbers to normal.